# Plex media server and mount issues in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab, mountpoint, plex

hopefully it's not too much of a newbie question......

so, i have decided to drop plex media server onto an Ubuntu install in order to provide my house with a stable platform that will maximize availability. I had considered setting up an old WinXP machine to do this, but figured that i would get the most out of older hardware on Ubuntu, and that it would make full use of all the RAM as it's a 64bit OS instead of 32bit.

that being said, I'm having some issues. My machine is currently an older:

- 13.04 64bit.
- AMD2.7 dual core w/
- 8GB RAM

my Linux knowledge is pedestrian at best, but I do have some command line experience.  my question is thus......

I have finally moved all my media over from a Windows 7 MCE machine that we were using, but was slowing down tremendously.  apparently Plex does not support sub folders and I had to redo my directory structure again, as I want to separate my video files into kid friendly categories (same with my music files). Because of this, i used `gparted` to create several different logical volumes that will be mounted independently from one another, and allow me to create different repositories within Plex, that our kids now they can access.

I know that the naming convention of the media (movies, tv progs, music, etc) must be adjusted so that Plex can find them.  however, I have done some reading and have found that this is probably not the only issue that I may be having. I have read other threads that indicate that the permissions on the volumes need to be `777` in order to allow Plex to access them, or Plex needs to be added to my default `usergroup`. This is not a concern, as I am probably going to be the only one accessing anything on the server, and i am comfortable with `chmod -R` enough to have fixed that. Additionally though, I read that the volumes are mounted with a default `/media` mountpoint and that this is the real underlying problem.  I read that the mountpoint needs to be changed to `/mnt`. In order to do this, it would appear as though I need to edit `/etc/fstab` in order to change the mountpoints.  I found this guide: [MoveMountpointHowto - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MoveMountpointHowto)

My question is after moving all my files into my directories and having them mount at `/media`, should I back the files out in order to change the mount point? Or perhaps a better way to phrase it, will my data still be in the partition after I change the mountpoint or will it be lost?  another set of questions, is this even necessary?  is there an easier way to change the mountpoint?  while i am somewhat ok w/ using the command line, i would prefer a GUI option as my Linux-fu is far outdated. Alas, i have been unable to find anything that is reliable and all the posts i have read is that editing the `/etc/fstab` is "easy".  i'm afraid that the "how to" article referenced above is something that I'm not 100% comfortable with, although it appears to be very well written.

thank you in advance for any input/feedback/assistance!

Comment: Your data will be safe, as changing mount point doesn't delete your data. But, always backup your data!

Comment: Volumes are mounted at /media *if you are using a method of mounting that puts them there*. If you mount using /etc/fstab or a script, then you can put your mount points almost anywhere in the filesystem. My experience with Plex is that the application will happily use any mount point that it has permission to see. /media is indeed required if you are using the Plexmediaserver *snap* due to it's built-in confinement...but you almost certainly are not using a snap on 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

well the safest option is to always backup, secondly XBMC does a much better job at managing things like this, consider XBMC as an alternative

Comment: i had considered XBMC and use it as our media center front end with a Plex ad-on.  the reason i wanted to use Plex was for Chromecast (within the home) and the ability to access outside of the home network.  i will have to consider XBMC going forward though if this is not something i cannot address easily.  then i'll just have to figure out how to get XBMC to cast to my android or ipad while out and about.

Answer (score 0):

Having backups is always a good idea, but changing the mount points should not put you data at risk. How you create the mount points through editing `fstab` will depend on what type of partitions you created with `gptd` - NTFS, EXT, etc. Before you begin editing your `fstab` entries, simply make a backup of the current file with `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup`.

From what I know about Plex, it creates the user `plex` to run processes under and `plex` will need explicit permissions to the media directories. Partitions mounted through `fstab` will mount as `root`. You might be able to bypass this by having your media files stored in a top-level directory (say, "Media1" on the first partition) on each partition and assigning permissions to that folder and the enclosing folders with `sudo chown -R plex /media/mountpoint/Media1`. Otherwise, you will have to use `uid`, `gid` and `umask` values in the `fstab` entries for the partitions to get them to mount with the desired user `plex` with read/write privileges. I found [this article](http://www.omaroid.com/fstab-permission-masks-explained/) to be somewhat helpful in explaining `fstab` entries and setting `umask` bits.

Comment: so then, based upon your post, do i even need to change my mountpoints?  maybe you just used the /media mountpoint as an example and i'm confused.  :)  the partitions are all ext4 and i will certainly make a backup of the fstab.  thanks for your thoughts and insight!

Comment: If the partitions are auto-mounting already, you might get by with having the folders on them owned by `plex`. External drives and drives/partitions not used by Ubuntu directly get mounted in the `/media` directory rather than `/dev` or `/mnt` so I can see where the use of "media" can get confusing.

Comment: **sigh**  well, i've moved the partitions to /mnt i've added plex to the plugdev and user account groups.  still nothing....

Comment: So the partitions are mounted and the system sees them? Does Plex not recognize them, or what errors are you getting? Can you edit your question with the output of `ls -l` of the `/mnt` directory and of one of the partitions so we can see what's showing to the system?

Comment: sorry, got busy yesterday.  i'm trying one last thing today and then i'll try to post it here.